# C++ Ncurses displaying a timer

Tags: c++, timer, pthreads, ncurses

I want to display a timer in an ncurses window, one that ticks down from two minutes, but I don't really have any idea how to do this, would anyone here know how to and would be willing to help me? Or is this too general a question? I'm currently using pthreads in the program as well.

I should also specify this is for linux, so no windows libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
  int secondsLeft = 120;
  initscr();
  curs_set(0);
  do {
    printw("%i", secondsLeft);
    refresh();
    erase();
    secondsLeft--;
    napms(1000);
  } while (secondsLeft > 0);
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `sleep` is never best-practice.  `napms` is the recommended approach.  This answer additionally does not address OP's question about threads.